# Question about subgroups of elliptic curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

We discussed substructures in my Intro to Algebraic Structures class, and it got me thinking of structures that are defined by more than just its algebraic operations.

Consider some elliptic curve $E$. Are there ever any subgroups $E'\subset E$ of such a curve that are themselves elliptic curves, i.e., they satisfy some elliptic curve equation? If yes, is this "sub-elliptic-curve" structure ever used anywhere (maths, crypto, ...)?

Comment: Elliptic curves are objects of the algebraic geometry, we may see them as "group( object)s" in the category of varieties over some fixed field $\Bbb F$ (like $\Bbb Q$ or like some finite field). This object is *not* the same as the set of rational points $E(\Bbb F)$, for instance, for some finite field $\Bbb F$ we cannot reconstruct the object $E$ in algebraic geometry form the group structure of the finite group $E(\Bbb F)$. So in which "world" is asked the question? In the category of groups? ... of varieties? ("Some" morphisms are called isogenies... But "subgroup" does not make sense...)

Comment: Here's the answer to the dual of your question. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $K$. Given any finite subgroup $H$ of (the $\overline{K}$-points of) $E$, then the quotient $E/H$ is again an elliptic curve, and the map $E \to E/H$ is an isogeny. See Prop. III.4.12 of Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* for a proof.

Comment: As @dan_fulea mentions there is an important distinction to be made. If one takes an elliptic curve to be a smooth projective curve with marked point (from this you can deduce the group law) then it is easy to show that the only "sub ellipitc curves" are the curve itself (you could probably say this in terms of group varieties more cleanly). Why? If $\iota : E' \to E$ is a morphism of smooth proj. curves (we want this to be our inclusion) then $\iota$ is constant or surjective, but we want $\iota$ to be an inclusion (hence cannot take dim $1$ to dim $0$) so it must be surjective.